# Aligning the divs in a single line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two divs inside one div in a single line . I have tried with the following code:

```
<div style="width:100%">
 <div id="id1" style="width:40%;float:left;background-color:green;position:relative">
   float-left
 </div>
 <div id="id2" style="width:60%;float:right;background-color:yellow;position:relative">
 float-right
   <div id="id3" style="position:relative;left:0px">
   button1
   </div>
    <div id="id4" style="position:absolute;right:0px">
   button2
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need divs with id3 and id4 in the same line similar to span but I dont want to use a `span` tag , within id2 div?

I tried using position as both absolute and relative and combinations but it is not aligning within same line. What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `display:inline-block`

```html
<div style="width:100%">
 <div id="id1" style="width:40%;float:left;background-color:green;position:relative">
   float-left
 </div>
 <div id="id2" style="width:60%;float:right;background-color:yellow;position:relative">
   <div id="id3" style="display:inline-block;">
   button1
   </div>
    <div id="id4" style="display:inline-block;">
   button2
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```html
<div style="width:100%">
 <div id="id1" style="width:40%;float:left;background-color:green;position:relative">
   float-left
 </div>
 <div id="id2" style="width:60%;float:right;background-color:yellow;position:relative">
 float-right
   <div id="id3" style="position:relative;display:inline-block">
   button1
   </div>
    <div id="id4" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:0">
   button2
   </div>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to set `display: inline-block` like this:

```
 <div id="id2" style="width:60%;float:right;background-color:yellow;position:relative">
 float-right
   <div id="id3" style="display: inline-block;">
   button1
   </div>
    <div id="id4" style="display: inline-block;">
   button2
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You could also add the property `top: 0px` which will give you the same result. However, `display: inline-block` is much cleaner and exists because of your exact problem.

A `div` is initially a block and therefore spans the entire width of its parent element. This means `div`s are placed below each other, if they're not told to be `inline-block`s, which will make them "wrap" their content.

Add borders to your elements and see the difference of `inline-block` and just `block`.